# Why does this method only work when someone types one character?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am trying to hide a label when someone types on the search bar and dismisses keyboard.The following code only works however if someone types one character. If you type multiple characters it doesn't hide label on keyboard dismiss. Might be a little detail I am missing. Any help will be appreciated.

```
  -(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
  {
label.hidden=YES;  
  }
```

Comment: No, I didnt implement the searchbuttonlicked method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you haven't already implemented it here - you need to make sure you have also implemented the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` method.

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{ 
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```